# angular $scope not updating with validation errors coming from laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

hi i want to display laravel(5) form validation errors in angular.
this is my controller:

```
.controller('formController', function($scope,DocParamData,$state,$http,CSRF_TOKEN) {
     'use strict';

    $scope.docParam = $state.current.name.split('.');
    $scope.docParam = $scope.docParam[1];


    // we will store all of our form data in this object

    $scope.saveUser = function(user) {

   $http.post('/auth/register', {
     user:user,
    _token:CSRF_TOKEN
    }).success(function(v){

        return user;

  }).error(function(err) {

  $scope.errors = err;
    $scope.$apply();   
     return $scope.errors ;


    });
  };


$scope.getColumns = function(){

      $http.get('/columns/user').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.user = data;

      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });

  };


});
```

and my view (nested 'form.html' in register.blade.php):

```
    <div ng-repeat="e in errors">{{e}}</div>
```

no matter what i do - the $scope.errors doesnt update - console.log shows that $scope.errors has the correct data but only in the controller

[image: angular inspector- my it can help]

Comment: Why are you required to return $scope.errors? It doesn't make sense. $scope is accessible in page anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try using [angular.merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge) :

```
angular.merge(object1, object2);
```

Comment: merge $scope with what sir? @Balram Khichar

Comment: create an empty array

$scope.errors = [];


then use


`angular.mege($scope.errors, res);`

Comment: make sure your **res** in in proper format you're expecting

Comment: tried merge and the format is right. console.log() shows the errors. but still not displaying in html. when i harcode an array then its working..

Comment: can you paste the format of your **res** data  here?

Comment: {"first_name":["The first name field is required."],"last_name":["The last name field is required."],"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}  @Balram Khichar

Comment: first try printing `{{errors}}` and if you're getting data then try

`<div ng-repeat="e in errors">{{e[0]}}</div>`

Comment: i have tried that. nothing works. i am not new to angular although i am not a genious lol:) i tried $apply() to..im kind of lost here

Comment: here is the solution for your problem [http://jsfiddle.net/5xj1ynu8/](http://jsfiddle.net/5xj1ynu8)

'JSON.parse' is your saviour ;)

Comment: getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`. i have trie angular.toJson and angular.fromJson with no luck. do you maybe need to see more code? maybe it has anything to do with nested views? also just to be clear..i have all the other data coming the same way from back to front...all form fields ext...all with ng repeat...only the $scope.errors is a problem

Comment: check the jsfiddle link i posted